# Elasticseach Custom analyser for numeric string

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this kind of issue: I have a numeric string field, seperated with dots, like "1.1.2", "11.2.1", and the like. I have a requirement to do sorting by this field, and when I try to sort by that field, it does String sorting. So I should write an analyser, so that here, in this sample, "11.2.1" comes first when 'desc' sorting by this field. I do my mapping and setting this way:

```
    PUT your_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "custom_sort_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "dot_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "numeric_sort_filter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "dot_tokenizer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "\\."
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "numeric_sort_filter": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "(\\d+)",
          "replacement": "$1",
          "lowercase": true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "your_field": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "custom_sort_analyzer",
        "fielddata": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But again, getting not correct behavior when I'm doing this kind of sorting :

```
{
  "query": "my_query",
  "sort": [
    {
      "my_field": {
           "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those values look like are version numbers, and if that's the case there's a simpler option by using the [`version` field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.8/version.html) which works exactly the way you like.

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "version": {
        "type": "version"
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT test/_doc/1
{ "version": "1.1.2"}
PUT test/_doc/2
{ "version": "11.2.1"}
```

Then the following query returns 11.2.1 first

```
POST test/_search?sort=version:desc
```